# Clean data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
    Datum   Unternehmen     Event
0   9 Termine vom 01.01.2016 bis zum 31.12.2017     9 Termine vom 01.01.2016 bis zum 31.12.2017     NaN
1   9 Termine vom 01.01.2016 bis zum 31.12.2017     NaN     NaN
2   Datum   Unternehmen     Event
3   12.05.2017  ADIDAS AG   Dividenden
4   09.11.2017  ADIDAS AG   Ergebnisberichte
5   03.08.2017  ADIDAS AG   Ergebnisberichte
6   11.05.2017  ADIDAS AG   Hauptversammlung
7   04.05.2016  ADIDAS AG   Ergebnisberichte
8   03.03.2016  ADIDAS AG   Ergebnisberichte
9   04.08.2016  ADIDAS AG   Ergebnisberichte
10  03.11.2016  ADIDAS AG   Ergebnisberichte
11  12.05.2016  ADIDAS AG   Hauptversammlung
```

And I want to keep the rows(!) with an apparent date only.

At the moment, I am iterating with `df.iterrows()` and check the value with a regular expression (`r'^[\d.]+$'`) but I wonder if there's a more "pythonic way" as `iterrows()` is very slow when applied to a couple of hundred dataframes.

Comment: How did you generate your DF? I think you should check that part...

Comment: @MaxU: Scraped from a website with `scrapy` and `pd.read_html()` afterwards.

Comment: Can you share a link?

Comment: `df.apply(lambda x: yourfunction(x))` would be equivalent. if you want to apply your function row wise you could add argument `axis=1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) with parameter `errors='coerce'` and check where are not `NaN` with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
print (pd.to_datetime(df.Datum, errors='coerce'))
0           NaT
1           NaT
2           NaT
3    2017-12-05
4    2017-09-11
5    2017-03-08
6    2017-11-05
7    2016-04-05
8    2016-03-03
9    2016-04-08
10   2016-03-11
11   2016-12-05
Name: Datum, dtype: datetime64[ns]

print (pd.to_datetime(df.Datum, errors='coerce').notnull())
0     False
1     False
2     False
3      True
4      True
5      True
6      True
7      True
8      True
9      True
10     True
11     True
Name: Datum, dtype: bool
```

```
print (df[pd.to_datetime(df.Datum, errors='coerce').notnull()])
         Datum Unternehmen             Event
3   12.05.2017   ADIDAS AG        Dividenden
4   09.11.2017   ADIDAS AG  Ergebnisberichte
5   03.08.2017   ADIDAS AG  Ergebnisberichte
6   11.05.2017   ADIDAS AG  Hauptversammlung
7   04.05.2016   ADIDAS AG  Ergebnisberichte
8   03.03.2016   ADIDAS AG  Ergebnisberichte
9   04.08.2016   ADIDAS AG  Ergebnisberichte
10  03.11.2016   ADIDAS AG  Ergebnisberichte
11  12.05.2016   ADIDAS AG  Hauptversammlung
```

If need convert column `Datum` to `datetime`:

```
df.Datum = pd.to_datetime(df.Datum, errors='coerce')

print (df.Datum.notnull())
0     False
1     False
2     False
3      True
4      True
5      True
6      True
7      True
8      True
9      True
10     True
11     True
Name: Datum, dtype: bool

print (df[df.Datum.notnull()])
        Datum Unternehmen             Event
3  2017-12-05   ADIDAS AG        Dividenden
4  2017-09-11   ADIDAS AG  Ergebnisberichte
5  2017-03-08   ADIDAS AG  Ergebnisberichte
6  2017-11-05   ADIDAS AG  Hauptversammlung
7  2016-04-05   ADIDAS AG  Ergebnisberichte
8  2016-03-03   ADIDAS AG  Ergebnisberichte
9  2016-04-08   ADIDAS AG  Ergebnisberichte
10 2016-03-11   ADIDAS AG  Ergebnisberichte
11 2016-12-05   ADIDAS AG  Hauptversammlung`
```

Comment: Thank you, did not know about the `coerce`. Have a look at my answer though, this was what I was looking for.

Comment: Yes, I dont understand your question. Nice day!